# admob ads overlapping textview

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I'm trying to add an Admob banner (at the top) to a the main activity (my main app screen), but I face tiny problem which is the admob ad overlapping textview

this is my main activity xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_top_margin"
    
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        
        <!--  First header line -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/header_priority"
            android:layout_width="31dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#00F"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_tiny"
            android:text="@string/pri_label"
            />
        
        <!--  First header line -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/header_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#00F"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_tiny"
            android:text="@string/desc_label"
            />
    
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llPriority"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutHeader" >

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llPriority"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPriority"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_priority"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="@string/num_1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tvItemText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/add_hint">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:onClick="onClickAddItem"
            android:text="@string/add_button_label" />
    </LinearLayout>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, RelativeLayout allows overlapp, but within RelativeLayout you can arrange the alignments of the view elements, too. Just figure out the id of the view element that overlaps with your adview and add the following attribute to your `AdView` (I am assuming it's overlapping with `linearLayoutHeader`)

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutHeader"
```

You (or someone else that works on the same project?) actually **already did make use of these attributes** to arrange the views. Study the for example the following part of the code ;-)

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/llPriority"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutHeader" >

 </ListView>
```

Comment: not exacly what i did. but you help me a lot. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the root layout is a relativelayout which allows overlap, the other layouts you use are linear which are meant for stacking controls.

Comment: so what i shoul do? im a newbie as u can see

Comment: RelativeLayout -> LinearLayout, but you really should search for a Android layout tutorial.